# What's the non-recursive version of diff in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

The Clojure.data diff function recurses into all sub-sequences.

Is there a non-recursive version of diff that will just compare the top level?

Comment: Couldn't you use the fact that "Sets are never subdiffed" by [Clojure.data/diff](http://conj.io/1.6.0/clojure.data/diff/)?

Comment: You could fork this nice library and build your own version https://github.com/friemen/diffit/tree/master/src/diffit